# What is the reason for adding "bearer " as the prefix to your web token?

Tags: jwt, token

I saw a tutorial that does this. But I see absolutely no reason why one would ever need to add a prefix, any prefix, to your JWT token.

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Why is 'Bearer' required before the token in 'Authorization' header in a HTTP request?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/108662)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Bearer` is used in authorization tokens to distinguish it from other types of authentication, such as [`Basic`, `Digest`, and several others](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml). The `Authorization: <type> <credentials>` syntax was first described in the [HTTP 1.0 spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1945#section-10.2), long before the concept of a `Bearer` token was introduced in the [OAuth 2.0 authorization standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6750).